# Pandas dataframe - Remove part of string based on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete part of the string in a col_a based on the col_b.

ex :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['School 1 25 Queen Street','25 Queen Street'],['99 Main Street High School 2','99 Main Street']]), columns = ['Col a','Col b'])
```

| Col_a | Col_b |
| --- | --- |
| School 1 25 Queen Street | 25 Queen Street |
| 99 Main Street High School 2 | 99 Main Street |

I want to remove in the col_a the information from the col b :

| New_col_a |
| --- |
| School 1 |
| High School 2 |

I tried with the replace function with no success...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use - > `df['New_Col_a'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col_a'].replace(x['Col_b'], ''), 1)
`

Answer (score 1):

We can put a string replace inside of a lambda expression and apply that to each row of the dataframe.

```
df['Col a'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col a'].replace(x['Col b'], ''), axis = 1)
```